# Number of input does not equal amount of outputs (Python Bug)

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to fix a bug in a piece of code my computer sciences teacher has given the class. The due date is coming up, this is the last resort.

The problem is that the while true loop repeats:

```
filling_number = int(input("\n Please select a piece of filling, you can order a max of 5: "))
```

6 times, and then output (The `filling_order` array) only = 5.

I need the code to ask for 5 inputs, then save them to the filling_order array, and then show the array after the `if len(filling_order) >= max_length`.

I tried changing the `while true` to
`while len(filling_order) < max_length`.
which made it give me 1 input and 1 output.

What about it.

here's the code.
Go ham.

```
filling_array = ["Tomato", "Lettuce", "Cucumber", "Beetroot", "Bacon", "Cheese", "Avocado", "(NONE)"]
filling_order = []

loop_count = 0
max_length = 5

print("\n Please pick a filling\n")

while loop_count < len(filling_array):
    print (str(loop_count + 1)+")",str(filling_array[loop_count]))
    loop_count = loop_count+1

def filling_ordered():
    while True:
        len(filling_order) <= max_length # Checks if the length of filling_order list is less than or equal to the max_length variable
        try: # Validating inputs
            
            filling_number = int(input("\n Please select a piece of filling, you can order a max of 5: "))
            if filling_number < 1 or filling_number >= 9:
                print("Refer to Filling MENU for a valid number  line 22")
                continue
            if len(filling_order) >= max_length:
                print("\n Here is your order, you have chosen a maximum of 5 pieces of filling: ", filling_order)
                break
                
            else:
                filling_number -=1 #Takes one from the user input as python starts at 0 (e.g Tomato is 0)
                filling_order.append(filling_array[filling_number])# Takes the users input from filling_number (-1), uses it as an index position from the filling_array, adds it to the filling order array
                print("\n Your choice was: " + filling_array[filling_number])# Prints out the result of the output above (index postion of filling_array)

        except ValueError: #Validating inputs - accepts only numbers and can't be left blank 
                  print("Please use numbers only")
                  continue

        
filling_ordered()
```

Comment: Your prof may see that some student is asking for help on public sites though. Remember you can't delete question when someone answered (and some other conditions)

Comment: Has your "computer science teacher" told you about *enumerate*, *f-strings*, *set* and other useful constructs that would help with this task? Can the user select the same filling more than once? Does the user have to pick 5 fillings?

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow for **up to** 5 filling selections. No filling can be selected more than once. Perhaps this will help you with the structure of your code:

```
filling_array = ["Tomato", "Lettuce", "Cucumber", "Beetroot", "Bacon", "Cheese", "Avocado"]

MAX_SELECTIONS = 5

assert len(filling_array) >=  MAX_SELECTIONS

fillings = []

while len(fillings) < MAX_SELECTIONS:
    for i, e in enumerate(filling_array, 1):
        print(f'{i}) {e}')
    try:
        selection = int(input('Select a filling (0 to end): '))
        if selection == 0:
            break
        if 1 <= selection <= len(filling_array):
            fillings.append(filling_array.pop(selection-1))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Out of range: {selection}')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e, '\a')

if fillings:
    print('Selected fillings:-', *fillings, sep='\n')
else:
    print('No fillings were selected')
```